# How to get the parent of the Bootstrap slider which triggers the change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I have two Bootstrap sliders, initialized and ready. I have attached change event to them, but I am unable to get which slider is changing, as change event gives me an object containing newValue and oldValue. **I need to get the *event.target* to find the parent of the slider which is triggering the change event.**

Here is the code that I have so far :

**HTML FIXTURE**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <span id="slide-label">Example slider label</span>
    <input class="slide" id="slide_1" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <span id="slide-label">Example slider label</span>
    <input class="slide" id="slide_2" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
let slide_arr = [
            {
                id: 'slide_1',
                min: 1,
                max: 4,
                step: 1,
                value: 1,
                tooltip: "hide",
                ticks: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                ticks_labels: ["item a", "item b", "item c", "item d"]
            },
            {
                id: 'slide_2',
                min: 1,
                max: 4,
                step: 1,
                value: 1,
                tooltip: "hide",
                ticks: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                ticks_labels: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
            }];

        let slider_instance = [];

        for (let index = 0; index < slide_arr.length; index++) {
            const slide_obj = slide_arr[index];
            slider_instance[index] = new Slider(`#${slide_obj.id}`, slide_obj);
        }

        for (let index = 0; index < slider_instance.length; index++) {
            const slider = slider_instance[index];
            slider.on('slideStart', function (e) {
                console.log('slideStart')
                console.log(e);
            });
            slider.on('slideStop', function (e) {
                console.log('slideStop')
                console.log(e);
            });
            slider.on('change', function (e) {
                console.log('change')
                console.log(e);
            });
            slider.on('slide', function (e) {
                console.log('slide')
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
```

I have tried a lot of events and none are helping.

I have made [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StormRaider2495/304gzxw2/) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I have made a fiddle of the above
[https://jsfiddle.net/StormRaider2495/304gzxw2/](https://jsfiddle.net/StormRaider2495/304gzxw2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the target you're changing, you can use `slider.$element` and `slider.$sliderElem` in your case.

```
slider.on('change', function(e) {
    // I think this is what you actually want (#slide_1 or #slide_2)
    console.log(slider.$element)

    console.log(slider.$sliderElem) // This is the horizontal slider
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hikarunomemory/1s8rsua8/1/)

Comment: Can you provide a documentation for this?
Bootstrap-slider documentation did not mention of this.
For I need to know how this works.

Comment: I didn't find the documentation when I faced the same issue. So I just checked every variables that I can find to search for the information I need.

Comment: But I think if you have enough patience and time, you can find these in the [js](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-slider.js)

Comment: It is working for me as well. I just wish the documentation was more helpful.

Comment: Did you run into any problem where the label CSS from the slider.js won't load on slider initialization?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it's hard to tell what might occurs the problem until we see your codes (or settings).

Comment: Did you use the relayout function?
It says
Renders the tooltip again, after initialization. Useful in situations when the slider and tooltip are initially hidden.
which fits my case perfectly as I am using the bootstrap slider on a carousel.

Comment: If my memory serves me right, I used `slider.slider("relayout");` to fix my problem. If you ran into any situation that you couldn't figure out how to solve it, just post another question with your codes that demonstrate your issue. I think that would be someone can help you with the issue.